# Can a form be submitted from within a handlebars script template to post an update?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, templates, handlebars.js

Am using handlebarsJS on both the front-end and back-end (with node.js), and AJAX to post data to the node.js API, which is working perfectly (as tested with Postman)

Is there a way to submit forms within a client-side handelbars template script?

Right now, nothing logs, and nothing happens graphically when clicking the input button, which otherwise works for new ajax posts, without the handlebars scripting of course..

Here's the HTML/HandlebarsJS:

```
<div id="allStories" class="allStories"> </div><!--/allStories-->
<script id="storyTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

  <div class="thisness">
      <div class="stories">

          <div class="new" id="new">
            \{{#each stories}}
              <div class="row moreTop1">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                  <form id="updateStoryForm">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                      </span>
                      <input type="hidden" id="storyID" value="\{{ _id }}"/>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="currentStory" value="\{{ story }}">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="button" id="UpdateStory">
                      </span>
                    </div><!-- /input-group -->
                  </form>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
              </div><!-- /.row -->
            \{{/each}}
          </div>

      </div> <!--/stories-->
    </div> <!--/thisness-->

</script>
```

And here's the AJAX Update:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // UPDATE
  // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

  // UpdateStory button clicks
  $( "#UpdateStory" ).click(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      // story elements for API
      var id = $( "#storyID" ).val();
      var story = $( "#currentStory" ).val();
      var datetimeNow = new Date();

      if($("#archiveCheck").is(":checked")) {
          archive = true;
      } else {
          archive = false;
      }

      console.log(id);
      console.log(story);
      console.log(datetimeNow);
      console.log(archive);

      var AjaxPostData = {
          id : id,
          story : story,
          datetimeNow : datetimeNow,
          archive : archive
      };

      console.log(AjaxPostData);

      // if the story field has content
      if (story.length != 0) {
        console.log('there is a story: ' + story);
          // make an ajax call
          $.ajax({
          dataType: 'json',
          data: AjaxPostData,
          type: 'post',
              url:"http://localhost:4200/api/v1/stories" + id,
              success: refreshNewStories,
              error: foundAllNewFailure
          });
      };

      console.log(AjaxPostData.id);

  }); // UPDATE


}); // doc is ready
```

Comment: Does it work if you change from an ID selector to a class selector? Since you're looping in the DOM, the `#UpdateStory` id won't be unique. Try `.UpdateStory` and change it to a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem is,

the handlebar inserts the form into the DOM after the 'event' binding has taken place. 
so during event binding, when the jquery looks for the updatestory element it's not present.

You need to use the jquery 'On' function.

let's say: you want to bind event to element 'B',

you need to select any parent element of B, and using the jquery ON method  and bind event to all 'present and future' element A under element B.

Solution:

1.) change id to class //Not necessary, but recommended.

2.)

```
// The parent elment should be dom element which is present in the dom. 
//You can move up to even $('document')

   var parentElment = $('currently-existing-parent-element-of-the-button-you-want-to-bind-the-event-to'); //: P 
    parentElement.on('click','.UpdateStory',function(e) {

                                                       });
```

Eg:

```
$('document').on('click', '.UpdateStory', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('xyz');
}
);
```

**Note:** Don't copy paste the code, it won't work, it's only for explanation.

ref: [jQuery On() - EventHandler Attachment](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: even after changing the form id="UpdateStoryForm" to a class, and changing the event to `$(".updateStoryForm").on('click','.UpdateStory',function(e) {` and adding a console.log right after this onClick event, nothing records in the console?! Any other suggestions?

Comment: updateStoryForm is the parent? and this parent is not inserted using handlebar?

Comment: the updateStoryForm is also inserted using handlebar. you will need to move up and attach it to a dom element that is already present in the dom, it can even be $('document')? you got me?

Comment: well, the direct parent would be `span class="input-group-addon">`, but that doesn't include the input fields, though I tried biding to this too..

Comment: $('document').on('click','.UpdateStory',function(event){event.preventDefault(); console.log('xyz');});

Comment: nice! it's doing something!! will debug for a few minutes, though from the looks of it you're getting the 50 point bounty! Many, many thanks for this

Comment: am glad it works, the 'on' function is very useful. read up on it..: )

Comment: p.s. document doesn't seem to work, as in your comment, but the allStories class that surrounds the templating does!

Comment: ok, after some debugging.. am getting `TypeError: 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement`, though this doesn't seem to really affect anything.. Although, the form field elements to update need some uniqueness because it's grabbing the first element regardless

Comment: you can fix that by changing the selector from class to ID (provided they are unique)

Comment: i guess, the issue with event binding has been resolved.

Comment: yes, you get the bounty, absolutely.. really grateful for the solution.. will continue to debug from here.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't post data without form, or you can do this by creating json object and send it to the specific url

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
<form name="input" action="http://localhost:4200/api/v1/stories" method="post">
```

And

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

?